# C# Crashing after modifying static variable during benchmarking

Tags: c#, crash, benchmarking, static-members, b-tree

I have implemented B-Tree and now I am trying to find the best size per node. I am using time benchmarking to measure the speed.
The problem is that it crashes on the second tested number in benchmarking method.
For the example down the output in console is

```
Benchmarking 10
Benchmarking 11
```

The crash is in insert method of Node class, but it does not matter because when I tested using any number as SIZE it works well. Maybe I do not understand how the class objects are created or something like that.

I also tried calling benchmarking method with variuos numbers from main, but same result, during second call it crashed.

Can somebody please look at it and explain me what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

I put part of the code here and here is the whole thing http://pastebin.com/AcihW1Qk

```
public static void benchmark(String filename, int d, int h)
{
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename))
    {
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    for(int i = d; i <= h; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Benchmarking SIZE = " + i.ToString());
        file.WriteLine("SIZE = " + i.ToString());
        sw.Start();
        // code here
        Node.setSize(i);
        Tree tree = new Tree();
        for (int k = 0; k < 10000000; k++)
            tree.insert(k);

        Random r = new Random(10);
        for (int k = 0; k < 10000; k++)
        {
            int x = r.Next(10000000);
            tree.contains(x);
        }
        file.WriteLine("Depth of tree is " + tree.depth.ToString());
        // end of code
        sw.Stop();
        file.WriteLine("TIME = " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
        file.WriteLine();
        sw.Reset();
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    benchmark("benchmark 10-11.txt", 10,11);
}
```

Comment: What is in the exception thrown?

Comment: NullReferenceException and it is on this line in Node.insert method                                                                `if (children[placeIndex].insert(x) == true)`                         The interesting thing is that it happen when I try to insert same number as size or bigger

Comment: Is your Tree object part of the .net framework or is it a custom object?

Comment: Tree and Node are my objects, you can look at the code at pastebin linked in question.

Comment: That website is blocked on the network im on at the moment. Sorry!